# ConTeXt: XML processing and buffers

Tags: context, xml

Knowing that buffers and macros don't play well together, I started with the [Verbatim XML](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Verbatim_XML) guide from the wiki.

However manipulating the catcode table is insufficient when trying to pass `xmlflush` into a `userdata` environment:

```
\startxmlsetups xml:initialize
  \xmlsetsetup{#1}{*}{xml:*}
\stopxmlsetups

\startxmlsetups xml:data
  \pushcatcodetable
  \setcatcodetable\ctxcatcodes
  \startuserdata[xyz]    % < trouble here
    \xmlflush{#1}
  \stopuserdata
  \popcatcodetable
\stopxmlsetups

\xmlregistersetup{xml:initialize}

\defineuserdata[xyz][alternative=xyzalt]
\defineuserdataalternative[xyzalt][renderingsetup=xyzimpl]

\startsetups[xyzimpl]
  \getinlineuserdata % no other options for now
\stopsetups

\startbuffer[buf]
<data>123123</data>
\stopbuffer

\starttext
  \xmlprocessbuffer{buf}{buf}{}
\stoptext
```

Running context gives:

```
tex error       > runaway error: end of file encountered
mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 1
```

How can I process subnodes with `xmlflush` or something similar and load the result into `start/stopuserdata`?

Other examples I found dealt with `xmlfunction` and processing a single node with Lua: here it might be the case that `<data>` has children nodes, hence the desire to process the subtree completely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `userdata` environment is based on the `buffer` mechanism and doesn't work without problems in the argument of other commands (all `setups` environments are just fancy macro definitions).

The linked XML page already provided a few tips how the `userdata` can be used with the help of the `\xmlfunction` command.

```
\startluacode
    function xml.functions.userdata(t)
        context.startuserdata({"xyz"})
        lxml.flush(t)
        context.stopuserdata()
    end
\stopluacode

\startxmlsetups xml:data
    \pushcatcodetable
    \setcatcodetable\ctxcatcodes
    \xmlfunction{#1}{userdata}
    \popcatcodetable
\stopxmlsetups
```

Comment: Thank you, sensei. So much to learn. If someone's curious why it's `lxml.flush`, the Lua binding is here: https://source.contextgarden.net/tex/context/base/mkiv/lxml-ini.lua?search=applyfunction#l74